# Ionic 4 + React + Capacitor app API calls works on browser but not working on device

Tags: reactjs, api, ionic4, capacitor

I am using Ionic4 + React. I have API serve with CORS enabled for all origins.
the API integration works perfect on chrome browser.
But when I run it on Android device using Capacitor the API fails with status as "failed".
[image]

Comment: I am using actual android device.

Comment: are there any errors on console?

Answer (score 0):

I tried on another Andriod xiaomi Android 8.1 phone and it worked.
But it is still not working on Mobistart Android 8.1